# Stop debugging Visual Studio 2013 when browser closes

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I automatically stop debugging Visual Studio 2013 when I close the browser window?

Comment: Are you debugging in IE?

Comment: I am debugging in chrome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only Internet Explorer can do this, as it's both a Microsoft product. Since Chrome has no direct access to Visual Studio it would be weird if Chrome could cut down the IIS process which is running on your PC.

If you like to see the "Stop debug behavior" you should use Internet Explorer as debug browser.

Comment: This is the behavior I see when using IE in pre-Visual Studio 2013 versions but I'm no longer seeing this when using VS 2013. Maybe there is some other option for it somewhere? Nothing I've found yet.

Comment: This solved the same issue for me in VS2015,  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Aware this is an old thread, but adding because this came up for me first trying to work out why VS2015 wouldn't stop debugging when I closed Internet Explorer. Turns out, being 64-bit, is had picked the x86 version of IE to browse with and of course I never noticed the difference. When I went to "Browse with", there was "Internet Explorer (2)" there, which was the 64-bit version. That stopped debugging fine when I closed IE. When I went back in to Browse With, the original X86 one was gone.

Presume because this was an old project that had the x86 association saved.