# Stop Visual studio debugger when closing Chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome

After looking all over the web for solution, I give up.
Is it possible to make chrome close when you stop the debugger and make the debugger stop when you close chrome, like it does with IE?
Maybe there is an addin that does this?
I'm using both vs 2010 and 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: This was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796651/stop-debugging-visual-studio-2013-when-browser-closes

Answer (score 5):

Only Internet Explorer can do this, as it's both a Microsoft product. Since Chrome has no direct access to Visual Studio it would be weird if Chrome could cut down the IIS process which is running on your PC.

If you like to see the "Stop debug behavior" you should use Internet Explorer as debug browser.

[Stop debugging Visual Studio 2013 when browser closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796651/stop-debugging-visual-studio-2013-when-browser-closes)