# Visual Studio 2013 Wont End Debugging When I Use Firefox Or Chrome To Debug My Asp.Net Project

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, visual-studio-2013

VISUAL STUDIO 2013 WONT END DEBUGGING WHEN i USE FIREFOX OR CHROME TO DEBUG MY ASP.NET PROJECT

I'm using Firefox to debug my asp.net project bcz I use ajax control toolkit v15 that has issues with debugging on IE it generates unsolvable JavaScript error

but I've noticed that after I close firefox or chrome I must press the stop button manually to stop the debug session is there is a solution for this issue

on IE it closes the debugging session but not firefox or chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Internet Explorer can do this, as it's both a Microsoft product. Since Chrome has no direct access to Visual Studio it would be weird if Chrome could cut down the IIS process which is running on your PC.

If you like to see the "Stop debug behavior" you should use Internet Explorer as debug browser.

[Stop debugging Visual Studio 2013 when browser closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796651/stop-debugging-visual-studio-2013-when-browser-closes)

[Visual Studio 2012 - stop debugging when IE closed](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_28172733.html)

Comment: in short term no solution for this issue --- ok better than the annoyying java error on IE